# Creating docker and anaconda

Tags: python, docker, jupyter-notebook

I have a Dockerfile that has a `FROM continuumio/anaconda3` that creates a anaconda3 with python 3.7.4.    I can run jupyter commands and process notebooks.  The image is documented here:  https://hub.docker.com/r/continuumio/anaconda3

But I need to change this image to run python 3.9.5.

There is a continuumio page with continuumio/conda-ci-linux-64-python3.9 but that doesn't allow jupyter notebooks to run.

How can I create a docker image that runs python 3.9.5 and has the jupyter commands?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion, installing your desire python version (3.9.5) in conda environment and then running jupyter is the way to go! The solution with my implementation ends up in this untidy Dockerfile!

```
FROM continuumio/anaconda3
RUN apt update

RUN conda create -n py39 python=3.9 pip
RUN echo "source activate py39" > ~/.bashrc
ENV PATH /opt/conda/envs/env/bin:$PATH
RUN mkdir -p /opt/notebooks
RUN /opt/conda/envs/py39/bin/pip install jupyter


CMD ["bash", "-c", "/opt/conda/envs/py39/bin/jupyter notebook \
    --notebook-dir=/opt/notebooks --ip='*' --port=8888 \
    --no-browser --allow-root"]
```

Comment: Thanks!   I had missed the pip on the command which took me down a rabbit hole (installing jupyter, etc) of the real problem.

Comment: I would start from miniconda, not anaconda and install just what you really need. It will be a smaller and faster image, see https://hub.docker.com/r/continuumio/miniconda3/dockerfile